# Is Jest a react native unit testing tool?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, jestjs

Is `Jest` a unit testing tool for `React-Native`? I need to perform functional validation on the UI layer of a `React Native` based app. Currently we use `Appium` for testing a `Native app` but since we are migrating our apps to `React Native` I was wondering if I can use `Jest`. But the more I read about `Jest` I'm starting to feel that it's a `unit testing` tool. Should I continue to use `Appium` or should I move to `Jest` if I want to perform functional validation on the UI of the native application?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for gray box e2e tests for `react-native` environment and mobile in general:

https://github.com/wix/detox

Comment: How is `detox` different from `jest` or `appium`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use Jest to test your Reactive Native application. Both they are designed to work together and crated by Facebook.

> At Facebook, we use Jest to test React Native application. [Ref](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-react-native.html).

What is interesting that starting from react-native version 0.38, a Jest setup is included by default when running `react-native i`.

I believe Appium can be used for visual regression testing when instead Jest can be use for snapshots comparisons (potentially they can work together).

> Snapshot testing and visual regression testing are two distinct ways
>   of testing UIs, and they serve different purposes. Visual regression
>   testing tools take screenshots of web pages and compare the resulting
>   images pixel by pixel. With Snapshot testing values are serialized,
>   stored within text files and compared using a diff algorithm. [Ref](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html).